# How to add a value to a textbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add a value from a HTML tag to a textbox with Javascript.

I have attempted with the Javascript below but it didn't work as `[object Object]`.

**Summary**: What I want here is to set the textbox which value should be **`Abc`**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="s4-trc-container-menu">
    <div>
        <span style="display: none">
            <menu largeiconmode="true" id="zz14_ID_PersonalActionMenu" type="ServerMenu">
                <ie:menuitem menugroupid="100" ></ie:menuitem>
                <ie:menuitem menugroupid="200" onmenuclick="javascript:LoginAsAnother('\u002f_layouts\u002fcloseConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true', 0)" type="option" id="zz16_ID_LoginAsDifferentUser"></ie:menuitem>
                <ie:menuitem menugroupid="200" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/_layouts/SignOut.aspx');" type="option" id="zz17_ID_Logout"></ie:menuitem>
                <ie:menuitem menugroupid="300" onmenuclick="javascript:ChangeLayoutMode(true);" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/menupersonalize.gif" type="option" id="zz18_ID_PersonalizePage"></ie:menuitem>
            </menu>
        </span>

        <span>
            <a href="javascript:;" accesskey="W" id="zz19_Menu" class="ms-menu-a">
                <span>Abc / Developer</span>
                <img style="border: 0px" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif">
            </a>
            <span class="s4-clust ms-viewselector-arrow" style="height: 3px; width: 5px; position: relative; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;" />
            <img style="border-width: 0px; position: absolute; left: -0px !important; top: -491px !important;" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<input id="ctl00_m_g_5a8c2c6f_548d_49e8_857c_1cc336cd42bc_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" type="text" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
    var get_requester = $(".s4-trc-container-menu div span a span");
    alert(get_requester.text());

    var set_requester = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_5a8c2c6f_548d_49e8_857c_1cc336cd42bc_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_TextField");
    set_requester.value = get_requester;
```

**JSFIDDLE:** **http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/7FfnA/**

Comment: `set_requester.value = get_requester.text()` ?

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7FfnA/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7FfnA/5/ is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you to everybody. I appreciate all your help! Now, I got the answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
set_requester.value = get_requester.text();
```

Try split..

```
var res = set_requester.value.split("/");
var abc=res[0];
alert(abc);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please tell me how I can put only `Abc` into the textbox's value?

Comment: Thank you again. That works well. This required me to wait for a period of time to give you a reputation as the best answer. If I did something wrong, please tell me. Anyway I have voted already for you.

Comment: That's great. I also appreciate all your help. We are here that means that we are always friends.

Answer (score 2):

your code improved a bit and now its working.

replace this with your code

```
var get_requester = $(".s4-trc-container-menu div span a span");
alert(get_requester.text());

var set_requester = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_5a8c2c6f_548d_49e8_857c_1cc336cd42bc_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_TextField");
set_requester.value = get_requester.text();
```

Here in finale line `set_requester.value = get_requester.text();`is the only change i made.

Here's the [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7FfnA/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
see link http://jsfiddle.net/7FfnA/2/
```

i think u r missing in last line

Comment: That's correct. Could I put only `Abc` into the textbox's value?

Answer (score 1):

There is one change needed in your code

`var get_requester = $(".s4-trc-container-menu div span a span");`

`alert(get_requester.text());`

`var set_requester = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_5a8c2c6f_548d_49e8_857c_1cc336cd42bc_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_TextField");`

```
set_requester.value =get_requester.text();
```

Answer (score 1):

change following in javascript ,
 actually you should assign value from get_requester to set_requester.text() .

```
  var get_requester = $(".s4-trc-container-menu div span a span");
     alert(get_requester.text());

      var set_requester =         document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_5a8c2c6f_548d_49e8_857c_1cc336cd42bc_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_TextField");
     set_requester.value = get_requester.text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if what you want is to set the text box to say

> Abc / Developer

just add `.text()` at the end. You basically answered your own question with the successful `alert()`

Comment: That's right. Thank you for your comment. Could I put only `Abc` into the textbox's value?

Comment: You could  - but then if you change the text inside the ``<span></span>`` it won't change in the text box. For generic reasons writing ``set_requester.value = get_requester.text() `` is the correct way - unless you don't plan on changing the value of the text box...

Comment: but to Answer your second question - yes you can ``set_requester.value = "Abc/Developer";``